# TypeScript Sequelize : How to join two tables with common

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

There are three tables.

**Tables** :

**Trip**

```
id | start_destination_id | end_destination_id | arrive_time |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 |          S           |          E         |    09:00    |
```

**Destination**

```
id | name
---------
S  | Start
E  | End
```

**Schedule**

```
id | start_destination_id | end_destination_id | should_arrive |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 |          S           |          E         |     08:00     |
 2 |          A           |          E         |     10:00     |
```

**Query**

```sql
SELECT 
    Trip.*,
    Schedule.should_arrive
FROM 
    Trip
LEFT JOIN 
    Schedule
ON 
    Trip.start_destination_id = Schedule.start_destination_id 
AND 
    Trip.end_destination_id = Schedule.end_destination_id
```

I am trying to include `Schedule` in `Trip.findAll` but receive error

`Exception: SequelizeEagerLoadingError: Schedule is not associated to Trip!`

Is there a way that I can join them together without using foreign keys and raw queries?

Many thanks.

Comment: You need to apply associations between the models in your code. Check the docs: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/associations.html and how to do it in typescript: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/typescript.html

Answer (score 5):

Finally I found a solution (not sure if it is a hack).

**Schedule.ts**

```
// add these lines
...
@ForeignKey(() => Trip)
@Column({ type: DataType.VIRTUAL })
private _dummyForTrip: undefined;
...
```

Then create an association between Schedule and Trip.

**Trip.ts**

```
@HasMany(() => Schedule)
public schedules: Schedule[] | null
```

Then you can include Schedule inside Trip by using `include.on`

```
    const trips = await Trip.findAll({
        include: [{
            model: Schedule,
            on: {
                '$schedules.start$': { [Op.col]: "Trip.start_destination" },
                '$schedules.end$': { [Op.col]: "Trip.end_destination" },
            }
        }],
        where: {
            id: { [Op.in]: payload.inputTripIdArr }
        }
    });
```